# When Trying to Post data and getting error "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"

Tags: swift4

When trying to Post data getting this error"The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var recipe_id: UITextField!
    var getdata = NSMutableData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBAction func Btn_Sav(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let url_str = URL(string:"http://iroidtechnologies.in/bigfish/Bigfish_cntrl/HealthyFish_Recipes_Detail")
        var url_req = URLRequest(url: url_str!)

        url_req.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "context_type")
        url_req.httpMethod = "Post"
        let Poststring = "recipe_id=\(recipe_id.text))"
        url_req.httpBody = Poststring.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url_req){(data,request,error) in

            if  let mydata_post = data
            {
                self.getdata.append(mydata_post)
                do
                {

                    let jsondata_post = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.getdata as Data, options: []) as! NSDictionary

                    print("jsondata_post------->",jsondata_post)
                }
                catch{
                    print("error",error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }

        };
        task.resume()

    }
```

When trying to Post data getting this error"The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is the optional `text` property which adds literal `Optional(` to the string, and the trailing `)` is probably not intended either.

You have to unwrap the optional (please name variables *lowerCamelCased*).

```
let postString = "recipe_id=\(recipe_id.text!)"
```

and the `httpMethod` string is supposed to be capitalized

```
urlReq.httpMethod = "POST"
```

Further delete `getdata`

```
var getdata = NSMutableData()
```

it's not needed and you should not use `NSMutableData` in Swift anyway. And use native Swift collection types rather than `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let jsondataPost = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
    ...
```